# How to plot points in a color corresponding to some value?

Tags: plotting

I want to attach one of two values (`1` or `-1`) to some coordinates in the plane and plot these points in a color corresponding to this value, e.g. `1` shall correspond to `Blue` and `-1` to `Red`. My coordinates and values are structured like this:

```
position = Table[{i, j}, {i, 0, 1}, {j, 0, 1}]
value = {{-1, -1}, {1, -1}}
```

In this example the coordinates `{0, 0}`, `{0, 1}` and `{1, 1}` have the value `-1` attached to them and I want to plot them `Red`, the coordinate `{1, 0}` has the value `1` attached to it, so I want to plot it `Blue` and so on. How can I do this?

Comment: So in `value`, a tuple `{a, b, c}` denotes a point `{b, c}` with color determined by `a`?

Comment: No, the table {{{a,b},{c,d}},{{e,f},{g,h}}} generated by position denotes the points {a,b}, {b,c}, {e,f} and {g,h} and value generates the corresponding values {{i,j},{k,l}}. So for example the value i corresponds to {a,b}, the value j to {c,d} and so on.

Comment: Something like `Graphics[{PointSize[Medium], MapThread[{#2 /. {-1 -> Red, 1 -> Blue}, Point[#]} &, {position, value}, 2]}]`, then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use `Style`:

```
position = Table[{i, j}, {i, -1, 1}, {j, -1, 1}];
value = {{1, -1, -1}, {1, 1, -1}, {1, 1, -1}};

data = Style[{#1, #2}, If[#3 == -1, Red, Blue]] & @@@ (* coloring *)
  Flatten /@ Transpose@{Catenate@position, Catenate@value} (* I find this data
                                                             structure convenient *)
```

[image]

```
ListPlot[data, Frame -> True, PlotStyle -> PointSize[Large]]
```

[image]

---

Or

```
red  = Catenate@Pick[position, value, -1]
blue = Catenate@Pick[position, value, 1]

ListPlot[{red, blue}, Frame -> True, 
 PlotStyle -> {Directive[PointSize[Large], Red], 
               Directive[PointSize[Large], Blue]}]
```

> plot as above

Answer (score 2):

There are many solutions. Here is mine:

```
Graphics[{
    PointSize[Large],
    Point[
        Flatten[position,1],
        VertexColors->Replace[Flatten@value,{-1->Red,1->Blue},1]
    ]
}]
```