# Basins of attraction for the Duffing equation with no forcing term

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, performance-tuning

I want to solve an ode for many different initial values and plot these initial values in a plane in

a) red if $(x,\dot{x})$ tends to $(1,0)$ for $t\to\infty$

b) blue if $(x,\dot{x})$ tends to $(-1,0)$ for $t\to\infty$

thanks to the answers to another [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/136179/how-to-plot-points-in-a-color-corresponding-to-some-value) I asked, I was able to get this

```
duffing = x''[t] + 0.02 x'[t] - .5 x[t] + .5 x[t]^3 == 0;
parametricsol = 
ParametricNDSolveValue[{duffing, x[0] == x0, x'[0] == v0}, {x, x'}, {t, 0, 4000}, {x0, v0}]

stepsize:=.05    

value := Table[
parametricsol[i, j][[1]][3000], {i, -1.5, 1.5, stepsize}, {j, -1.5, 1.5, stepsize}]
position := Table[{i, j}, {i, -1.5, 1.5, stepsize}, {j, -1.5, 1.5, stepsize}]

data := Flatten /@ Transpose@{Catenate@position, Catenate@value}

ListPlot[Style[{#[[1]], #[[2]]}, 
Which[#[[3]] == -1., White, #[[3]] == 1., Blue, #[[3]] == 0., 
 Red]] & /@ data]
```

If I'm not mistaken `ParametricNDSolveValue` solves the ode for around 3600 pairs of initial conditions and this takes around 2 minutes on my pc. For a nice looking plot the `stepsize=.05` is way too big but if i choose a smaller step size, say `.01`, it would take almost 1 hour till the computation is done. For a step size of `0.001` the computation would take more than 4 days… What can I do to make this faster?

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://books.google.com/books?hl=en&id=vpYmj7ohofsC&pg=PA308)?

Comment: thx, no i haven't. Do you know whether there is a discussion of the basin of attraction and how to get it in a fast/nice way in the book?

Comment: It's a hint to look in the book (in Google Books or maybe a hard copy borrowed from the nearby library) and find it out for yourself...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Update

Inspired by the [comment by J.M.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/136204/basins-of-attraction-for-the-duffing-equation-with-no-forcing-term#comment368210_136204), I managed to code a much faster implementation <strike>but to be honest I don't understand the math behind very well</strike>:

```
duffing = x''[t] + 0.02 x'[t] - .5 x[t] + .5 x[t]^3 == 0;
tbegin = -100;
pa2 = ParametricNDSolveValue[{duffing, x[0] == x0, x'[0] == v0}, 
   x, {t, tbegin, 0}, {x0, v0}];

{test[1], test[2]} = pa2[0, #] & /@ {10^-6, -10^-6};
dat = Transpose[#["ValuesOnGrid"] & /@ {test[#], test[#]'}] & /@ {1, 2};
(* Alternative method for obtaining dat: *)
(*
plot = ParametricPlot[{test[#][t], test[#]'[t]} & /@ {1, 2} // Evaluate, {t, tbegin, 0}]    
dat = Cases[plot, Line[a_] :> a, Infinity];
 *)

poly = Polygon@
    Join[dat[[#2]], 
     Reverse@dat[[#1]][[Position[dat[[#1]], First@Nearest[dat[[#1]], dat[[#2, 1]]]][[1, 
           1]] ;;]]] &;

{Red, poly[1, 2], Blue, poly[2, 1], Yellow, Point[{{1, 0}, {-1, 0}}]} // Graphics
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

Add a proper `"StopIntegration"` event to `ParametricNDSolveValue` will significantly speed up the calculation:

```
duffing = x''[t] + 0.02 x'[t] - .5 x[t] + .5 x[t]^3 == 0;
parametricsol = 
 With[{method = "DetectionMethod" -> "Sign"}, 
  ParametricNDSolveValue[{duffing, x[0] == x0, x'[0] == v0, a[0] == 0, 
    WhenEvent[x[t] == #, a[t] -> a[t] + #, method] & /@ {-1, 1}, 
    WhenEvent[a[t] == #, Sow@Sign@a[t]; "StopIntegration", method] & /@ {3, -3}}, 
   x, {t, 0, 4000}, {x0, v0}, DiscreteVariables -> a]]

value[{x_: 0}] := x
data = With[{stepsize = 1/100}, 
    ParallelTable[
     parametricsol[i, j] // Reap // Last // Flatten // value, {i, -1.5, 1.5, 
      stepsize}, {j, -1.5, 1.5, stepsize}]]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {545.779733, Null} dual core *)

ContourPlot[False, {x, -1.5, 1.5}, {xp, -1.5, 1.5}, 
  FrameLabel -> (Style[TraditionalForm@#, 15] & /@ {x, x'})]~Show~
 ArrayPlot[data\[Transpose], ColorRules -> {1 -> Red, -1 -> Blue, 0 -> Yellow}, 
  DataRange -> {{-1.5, 1.5}, {-1.5, 1.5}}, DataReversed -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: This colors the initial value blue (red) if x is round about -1 (1), right? Should have probably mentioned it but x' has to be round about 0 at the same moment. So I guess StopIntegration doesn't work then?

Comment: @freddy90 Managed to make the result more reliable, have a look.

Comment: Very nice! I also tried to get the separatrix but couldn't figure out how to get the color between the two curves. Thank you!

Comment: Great answer. You don't need to use `Cases` on the graphics object to get the coordinates for each solution. Consider using the methods for `InterpolationFunctions` instead, like `test[1]["ValuesOnGrid"]`.

Comment: @Pillsy Thanks for pointing out. (My thought was somewhat limited by the material given by J.M. 囧）I've added this method to my answer.

Comment: Slightly shorter: `dat = Table[Transpose[Through[{test[k], test[k]'}["ValuesOnGrid"]]], {k, 2}];` Also: `poly = Polygon[Join[dat[[#2]], dat[[#1]][[-1 ;; First[Nearest[dat[[#1]] -> Automatic, dat[[#2, 1]]]] ;; -1]]]] &;`

Comment: @J.M. Oh I didn't notice `Nearest` owns such a simple syntax for obtaining the position of the list element!

Answer (score 5):

**Comment**

I fail to see the point of taking a very very small step size. Even, with a few points you can get a reasonable plot.

```
sol[x0_?NumericQ]:=First@NDSolve[{x''[t] + 0.02 x'[t] - .5 x[t] + .5 x[t]^3 == 0, 
     x[0] == x0, x'[0] == x0}, {x}, {t, 0, 4000}];
With[{sol1 = {x[t], x'[t]} /. sol[#] & /@ Range[-1.5, 1.5, 0.05]}, 
  ParametricPlot[sol1, {t, 0, 4000}, PlotRange -> All,PlotPoints -> 500, 
MaxRecursion -> 5,AxesLabel -> {"x", "x'"}]] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image]

The next thing come to mind was to convert your second order ode to a system of first order odes, which happens to be a little faster than the first one.

```
soln[x0_?NumericQ] :=First@NDSolve[{x1'[t] == x2[t], 
     x2'[t] + 0.02 x2[t] - .5 x1[t] + .5 x1[t]^3 == 0, x1[0] == x0, 
     x2[0] == x0}, {x1, x2}, {t, 0, 4000}];
With[{sol2 = {x1[t], x2[t]} /. soln[#] & /@ Range[-1.5, 1.5, 0.05]}, 
  ParametricPlot[sol2, {t, 0, 4000}, PlotRange -> All, 
   PlotPoints -> 500, MaxRecursion -> 5, 
   AxesLabel -> {"x1", "x2"}]] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image]

A much faster way to do it, is to plot the stream lines and then impose the solution curves,

```
sp = StreamPlot[{x2, -0.02*x2 + 0.5*x1 - 0.5*x1^3}, {x1, -2, 
    2}, {x2, -2, 2}, StreamColorFunction -> "Rainbow"];
Manipulate[
 Show[sp, 
  ParametricPlot[
   Evaluate[
    First[{x1[t], x2[t]} /. 
      NDSolve[{x1'[t] == x2[t], 
        x2'[t] + 0.02 x2[t] - .5 x1[t] + .5 x1[t]^3 == 0, 
        Thread[{x1[0], x2[0]} == point]}, {x1, x2}, {t, 0, T}]]], {t, 
    0, T}, PlotStyle -> Red]], {{T, 4000}, 1, 
  100}, {{point, {-1.5, 1.5}}, Locator}, SaveDefinitions -> True]
```

[image]

I am thankful to @halirutan for teaching me how to use `AbsoluteTiming`.

Comment: I'm afraid this answer doesn't meet the requirement of OP, he wants a) red if the solution tends to $1$ for $t→∞$ b) blue if the solution tends to $-1$ for $t→∞$

Comment: @xzczd hmm... You are right. This is not a complete answer. My focus was on "What can I do to make this faster?"